# How to fix the height of a UINavigationBar in iOS11

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios11

The regular `UINavigationBar` with `prefersLargeTitle` property set to `true` changes its height dynamically if user changes text size based on user changing text size in device settings.

I am using a custom fixed font for the navigation bar title - So how do I fix the height of the navigation bar regardless of what text size a user chooses?

I tried to to set constraints on the height anchor of the navigation bar in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but it has no effect. The bar still increases its height if text size chosen by the user increases.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 96).isActive = true
```

Comment: This is for Objective C, but it might help. https://www.emdentec.com/blog/2014/2/25/hacking-uinavigationbar